# Properties of Interval Exchange Transformations

Tags: dynamical-systems

I'm studying a paper from Michael Keane on Interval Exchange Transformations.

Before I ask my question I explain a little about the subject:

Let $X=[0,1)$ and $n \geq 2$ an integer. For each probability vector $\alpha=(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \cdots, \alpha_n) $ with $\alpha_i >0$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$ we set :
\begin{align}
&\beta_0 =0\\ &\beta_i=\sum\limits_{j=1}^i\alpha_j\\&X_i=[\beta_{i-1},\beta_i)
\end{align}
Let $\tau$ be a permutation of the symbols $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$. Then
\begin{align}
\alpha^{\tau}=(\alpha_{\tau^{-1}(1)},\alpha_{\tau^{-1}(2)},\cdots, \alpha_{\tau^{-1}(n)})
\end{align}
is a probability vector with positive components, and we can form the corresponding $\beta_i^{\tau}$ and $X_i^{\tau}$, $1\leq i \leq n$. Now define $T:X \to X$ by setting
\begin{align}
Tx=x-\beta_{i-1}+\beta_{\tau(i)-1}^\tau
\end{align}
For each $ x \in X_i$ and each $ 1 \leq i \leq n$. $T$ maps each interval $X_i$ isometrically onto the corresponding interval $X_{\tau(i)}^\tau$.

We call $T$ an $(\alpha,\tau)$-Interval Exchange Transformation.

$T$ possesses the following properties:

1- $T$ is invertible, and its inverse is the $(\alpha^\tau, \tau^{-1})$ interval exchange transformation.

2- $T$ is continuous except at the points of the set $D=\{\beta_1,\beta_2,\cdots,\beta_{n-1}\}$ and $T$ is continuous from the right at these points.

3- $\lim\limits_{x\to \beta_i}Tx= \beta_{\tau(i)}^\tau$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$

4- $T\beta_i=\beta_{\tau(i+1)-1}^\tau$ for $0 \leq i \leq n-1$.

My question is to prove 3 and 4.

My try:

For 3:
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x \to \beta_i}Tx=T\beta_i &= \beta_i - \beta_{i-1}+\beta_{\tau(i)-1}^\tau\\
&= \alpha_i+ \beta_{\tau(i)-1}^\tau\\
&=\alpha_{\tau^{-1}(\tau(i))}+(\alpha_{\tau^{-1}(1)} + \cdots +\alpha_{\tau^{-1}(\tau(i)-1)})\\
&=\alpha_{\tau^{-1}(1)} + \cdots +\alpha_{\tau^{-1}(\tau(i)-1)}+\alpha_{\tau^{-1}(\tau(i))}\\
&=\beta_{\tau(i)}^\tau
\end{align}
Now how could I compute number 4? Where should I do a different thing in my calculation?

Answer (score 1):

I just found my answer... I got confused defining the map. It is why every interval $X_i$ is mapped isometrically to $X_{\tau(i)}^\tau$. Now depending where the $\beta_i$ is located, It is computed.